# Xcode with phonegap project Ipad simulator turns into iphone size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I started a phonegap project in xcode (3.2.6 with sdk 4.3). The example code should show a "Hello world" like message, and it does. But even when i selected the ipad simulator in xcode, and checked the "device" -> "Ipad" option to be selected it resizes the app to iphone format. I still see the simulator as an ipad, but the size of the app changes to iphone. Also the 2x button appears. So it looks like my phonegap project misses some config, or xcode is thinking it stills has to be run like an iphone app.  Anyone some experience and sollution for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iPad you need to build a new project. Because if you run the  iPhone project in iPad simulator then it will look as it looks in iPhone. So better to create two projects one for iPhone and other one for iPad.

Comment: Because i use phonegap as a user template within xcode there is no option to this template for picking iphone or ipad

Comment: For it, Select your project name -> target -> Device -> device -> iPad. You can choose universal for both. then select simulator as iPad

Comment: You really need to read this article http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/why_is_apple_rejecting_phonegap-built_iphone_apps.php